# lxterminal scrollback buffer size

Tags: scroll, terminal, buffer

I searched online for how to set the scrollback buffer size for lxTerminal, but the man page is mysteriously quite simple, missing any useful information. Is there a way to configure lxterminal to use a large scrollback buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's configurable via the preferences dialog

[image: dialog showing Preferences]

in the *Display* tab (where you can scroll the number up, or just fill in a large number which will be limited to **`100000`**):

[image: dialog showing Scrollback lines]

Regarding documentation - it uses VTE (same comment applies).